# setting default hash keys for mongoid hash field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a Mongoid model with a hash field. This Mongoid model has subclasses using single collection inheritance. Now I want to set **different default hash keys** for each subclass of the main model.

The main model

```
 class Sport
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :rules, type: Hash, default: {}
 end
```

Subclasses where I want to set different **default hash keys** for the **:rule hash field**. For instance, for football I want to have **rules: {:offside => '', :penalty => ''}** For Boxing we might have hash keys of **rules: {:biting => 'not allowed'}**. The open source app Errbit does something like it using constant in subclass to set default hash keys but I can see how they use the constant to populate the hash: https://github.com/errbit/errbit/blob/master/app/models/issue_trackers/github_issues_tracker.rb

```
 class Sport::Football < Sport
 end

 class Sport::Boxing < Sport
 end
```

I did overwrite the field definition in the subclass as shown below which works in the rails console. When I do **a = Sport::Football.new** and then call **a.smtp** returns the default settings. But the problem here is that when I go to the parent class and do **b = Sport.new** and **b.smtp**, I want it to be able to list all the default keys for the subclasses and it doesn't because **I have overridden the hash field in the subclass**.

```
 class Sport::Football < Sport
    field :rules, type: Hash, default: {:offside => '', :penalty => ''}
 end
```

Is there a way to set default hash keys for a subclass without overriding the **field definition**. It is okay to do this by overriding the setters and getters for the hash field in each subclass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:default` option can take a lambda as its value. Inside that lambda, `self` will be the new instance you're creating. That means that you can (indirectly) call methods to supply defaults:

```
class Sport
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :rules, type: Hash, default: lambda { default_rules }
end

class Sport::Football < Sport
private
  def default_rules
    { :offside => '', :penalty => '' }
  end
end

class Sport::Boxing < Sport
private
  def default_rules
    { :biting => 'not allowed except for ears' }
  end
end
```

You don't have to make `default_rules` private of course. You'll also want `default_rules` in `Sport` if you want to instantiate `Sport` directly.

You could also use one of the callbacks to set the rules by hand:

```
class Sport
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :rules, type: Hash
  after_initialize :set_default_rules, :if => :new_record? # Or one of the other callbacks.
end
```

and subclasses could say `self.rules = ...` in their `set_default_rules` implementations.

Comment: Thank you. The only change I needed to add was an empty method representing **default_rules** in the sports model. Without that, if I call **Sport.new** it throws the error **NameError: undefined local variable or method `default_rules'**. I okay leaving that there if there is no better to prevent that error.

Comment: That was intentional, I saw Sport as sort of a virtual base class that would never be instantiated itself (i.e. only the subclasses would be instantiated).

Comment: I was actually hoping that the usual `:default => :method_name` style would work but no joy (in Mongoid3 at least, might be worth a try in Mongoid4), hence the lambda indirection.